# Validação de formulario com javascript se pelo menos um dos inputs das linhas da tabela foram preenchidos antes de enviar o formulário?

Tags: javascript

> Segue o exemplo do formulário Note: em cada TR(Linha) o usuário
>   precisa preencher pelo menos um dos inputs. tipo escolha pelo menos um
>   dos dia da semana disponível.

```
<form>
<table id="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" > Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

A ideia é fazer uma função dinâmica que dê um foreach em cada  e depois verificar se pelo menos um dos inputs foram preenchidos.
Tipo, isso teria que ser feito em todas as linhas.
Todas elas precisam ter pelo menos 1 input preenchido.
Grato desde já pelo esforço

Comment: Não entendi o que tem de errado?

Comment: Já revisei e editei e nada....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é verificar os campos de cada linha dentro de um `for`. Se encontrar algum campo preenchido na linha, cancela o `for` com `break` e parte pra próxima. Se nenhum campo estiver preenchido numa linha, a variável de controle do `for` irá ficar com o valor igual ao número de elementos percorridos, logo, nenhum campo preenchido foi encontrado naquela linha e então você cancela o submit com `.preventDefault()` e mostra um alerta.

Sugiro colocar um id no `form` conforme abaixo, para que não haja possibilidade de conflitar com outro `form` que possa ter na mesma página:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   
   document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function(e){
      
      var tr = document.querySelectorAll("#tabela tr");
      
      for(var x = 0; x < tr.length; x++){
         
         var inps = tr[x].querySelectorAll("input");
         
         for(var i = 0; i < inps.length; i++){
            if(inps[i].value.trim()) break;
         }

         if(i == inps.length){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Preencha pelo menos uma opção em cada linha!");
            break;
         }
         
      }
   
   }
   
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
<table id="tabela">
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button> Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado!
Sua resposta é realmente bem funcional :)

Answer (score 1):

Acrescente uma função ao **onsubmit** do formulário para validar o formulário antes de enviar.
Na função **Enviar()**, recupere todas as linhas disponíveis na tabela e faça um laço nessas linhas. A cada interação do laço de linhas recupere todos os inputs disponíveis na linha e faça um outro laço, agora para os inputs. Em cada iteração do laço será recuperado os inputs disponíveis naquela linha.

Para cada input será verificado se o tamanho do conteúdo do input é maior do que 0, caso seja, é armazenado true em uma variáveld e controle. A cada verificação de linha, a variável de controle é testada para saber se seu valor é false (o que significa que todos os campos da linha são vazios), sendo false, é exibida uma mensagem e saí da função.

Ao final do laço de input e laço de linha é retornado verdadeiro e o formulário é submetido.

#### Segue código completo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return Enviar();">
        <table id="tabela">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="segunda" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quinta" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="sabado" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" > Enviar</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function Enviar(){
            var x = false;
            var linhas = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
                x = false;
                console.log('linha' + i);
                var inputs = linhas[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
                for(var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                    console.log('input' + j);
                    if(inputs[j].value.length > 0){
                        x = true;
                    }
                }
                if(x == false){
                    alert('Preencha pelo menos um campo por linha');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Guto, Obrigado pela resposta!
Eu testei agora seu código e não funcionou.
segue print: https://puu.sh/EfeWU/34f7941775.png

Ele só passou quando eu digitei em todos os inputs.

Comment: Você tem razão, vou modificar aqui.

Comment: E aí brow? 
Ainda por aí?

Comment: @Rafael Corrigi, da um olhada se funciona corretamente agora.

Comment: Agora sim!
Obrigado!
Vou analisar e aprender essa solução!!
Muito obrigado elo seu tempo!